# is my php image processing code secure?

Tags: php, image, security

I need some help to determine if my code is secure.
This is my function for resizing an image based on url rewrite.

URL rewrite code ... inside (.*) there is a string that tells the name of the product ... and I am using this method for SEO purpose, and the image is hosted on a different server, as I have multiple websites, and the image will also be resized to have smaller filesize.

```
RewriteRule mypic/(.*)/demo.gif$ preview.php?p=$1
```

PHP CODE . Each product has it's own folder with the preview picture, which was build for SEO purpose, derived from name. Something like

> 'www.mywebsite.com/products/eye-glasses-diesel/preview.gif'

This will be the data passed to the PHP : `products/eye-glasses-diesel/`

.

```
<?php
$src = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/'.$_GET['p'];
if (!$img = imagecreatefromgif($src."/preview.gif")){
    $img = imagecreatefromgif('http://www.mywebsite.com/na.gif');
}
// some image processing code like resizing,etc
// ......
header("Content-Type: image/gif"); 
imagegif($img); 
// Remove image 
imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think two basic checks are in order.

First you should standarize your names, (that's my humble proposition) and allow say only chars nad underscores (no number and other special chars) and check for that pattern on entry in your p param. So you will be protected from '../..' attacks.

Secondly Your question is somewhat not clear, and I thing there may be a possibility of loop ? That is your server will constantly trying to get an image, and instead of getting one, he would get directed to the code you presented and then again ? (It could DoS your server).

Comment: The code with the na.gif image is a picture that says "NOT AVAILABLE". That will always be found, so that will be what it shows if the product preview image fails to load.

As for your first suggestion, yes , I had that in mind, but when I look at preg_match checks I understand absolutely nothing. Maybe you can help ?

Comment: It's not an issue that the image will not be found, but rather that it will be done in continous loop when trying to find original gif. And for regular exps, you could go to http://www.regexplanet.com/ and test them before deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I think it safe yes, but you can improve performance.
It is better to take a little more disk space, and save the images from that resizes them each time you switch.

You can save the first time the image is requested, and after that display only the saved file. Here's an example: http://pastebin.com/2kzga4Zs